# Difference between original broadcast and Special Edition (OVA)

Tags: code-geass

There seems to be a difference in narrator for different versions of Code Geass' ending. One is narrated by Kallen, another narrated by C.C.

Which version is narrated by which person, and does it bring a tonal difference to the ending? Also, are there other significant changes between the original broadcast and the Special Edition (OVA) of Code Geass?

Comment: If it's about R2 ending, then both Kallen and C.C. did a narration at the end of episode 25; Kallen first, then C.C just before the ending credit... or did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: @AkiTanaka In this movie edition, the ending narration is different to the tv version:
https://youtu.be/BJcEVDS8QSY?t=6884
I am wondering if that narration changed the tone of the ending. Basically I hope I can find a translation to that.

Comment: Apparently, it's from the Special Edition (OVA). I removed reference to DVD/BD because there are DVD/BD for both the original anime and special edition.